# CakePHP 2: Multiple level join in Model Association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Let's say I have 3 models.

1. User (users of the system)
2. Applicant (More details on each user such as address, phone,
   interested_position, etc)
3. Position (In table applicants I only store interested position as position_id, this is
   where the position's description)

This is my model php files.

```
class User extends AppModel { 
  public $hasOne = 'Applicant'; 
}


class Applicant extends AppModel { 
  public $belongsTo = array('User', 'Position'); 
}


class Position extends AppModel { 
  public $hasMany = 'Applicant';
}
```

This is my UsersController.php

```
class UsersController extedns AppController {
  public function index() {
    $this->User->find('all');
  {
}
```

When execute /users/index I got SQL statement on SQL dump as follow.

```
select *
from users
  left outer join applicants
    on users.id = applicants.user_id
```

But this is what I need.

```
select *
from users
  left outer join applicants
    on users.id = applicants.user_id
  left outer join positions
    on positions.id = applicants.position_id
```

So what to do in CakePHP to get this kind of result.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:
Using the recursive attribute of a find to include a model's association's associations:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Using the containable behavior to do the same trick but with more control on the joins made in the request: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

The first solution is very simple, just add 'recursive' => 2 to your find('all'), the second solution is a bit more lengthy but has much much better performances.